# MacOS OpenGL fullscreen -> windowed issue

Tags: macos, opengl

I’ve got an OpenGL MacOS game, my MacOS is 10.13.4 with all recent updates.

When the game switches windowed -> fullscreen, everything is fine.

When is switches fullscreen->windowed it renders the full screen white, while in focus, but it renders fine when it not in focus.
And the game runs initially fine both in fullscreen and windowed modes.

The code is quite old, this is not the first game uses this code, and I don’t remember I saw this issue on previous MacOS versions.

Here is my code:

```
- (void)toggleFullscreen:(const bool)value
{
    if (value)
    {
        if (mFullScreenWindow)
            return;

        mFullScreenWindow = [[GameFullscreenWindow alloc] init];

        NSRect viewRect = [mFullScreenWindow frame];
        [mGameView stopDisplayLink:YES];
        [mGameView setFrameSize: viewRect.size];

        [mFullScreenWindow setContentView:mGameView];
        [mFullScreenWindow makeKeyAndOrderFront:self];

        RendererGLOSX::SaveDisplaySize(Vec2(viewRect.size.width, viewRect.size.height));
    }
    else
    {
        if (mFullScreenWindow == nil)
            return;

        NSRect viewRect = [mWindow contentRectForFrameRect:[mWindow frame]];
        [mGameView stopDisplayLink:YES];
        [mGameView setFrame:viewRect];

        [mWindow setContentView:mGameView];
        [mWindow makeKeyAndOrderFront:self];

        [mFullScreenWindow release];
        mFullScreenWindow = nil;

        RendererGLOSX::SaveDisplaySize(Vec2(viewRect.size.width, viewRect.size.height));
    }

    [mGameView stopDisplayLink:NO];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was `mFullScreenWindow` rendered.
The issue was fixed by adding `[mFullScreenWindow orderOut: self]` before `[mFullScreenWindow release]`.